# Exit Firefox Selenium Webdriver on ASP.NET Core application shutdown

Tags: c#, selenium, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

Using Selenium on ASP.NET Core MVC 2.1, I have a class that got injected by DI. It creats a `FirefoxDriver` instance, which shoult exite (close browser window and exit process) when the underlying ASP.NET Core application is terminated.

```
public class FFManager:IDisposable {
        RemoteWebDriver driver;
        public FFManager () {
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        }
        public void Dispose() {
            driver.CloseDriver();
        }
}
```

In `Startup.ConfigureServices`

```
services.AddSingleton<FFManager>(x => new FFManager());
```

#### Not working

As you can see, I implemented the `IDisposable` interface. The Firefox window is still open after process has exited. Another idea was to use the `applicationLifetime.ApplicationStopping` event in `Startup.Configure`

```
let manager = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<FFManager>();
manager.Dispose();
```

Same result. In the second approach, the event is definitely hit (breakpoint/console output tested) and the closing process of the ASP.NET Core app is a bit slower. But Firefox is still open after the app exited. Why?

When I change the lifetime of the service to scoped, the Firefox instance is closed after the request. But this should happen after app exit and not after each request. I don't get any errors, the app shutdown smoothly.

Comment: Rather than deleting your [same old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52880138/exit-firefox-selenium-webdriver-on-asp-net-core-application-shutdown) you should have updated the old question with your answers with respect to the answers asked by the contributors.

Comment: I don't know anything about ASP.NET, and not sure which driver you are using, but if you want to close browser for good, you need to use `Quit` or `Dispose` function of the driver, not `Close`. So look for equivalent of `driver.Quit();` or `driver.Dispose();`